# Get value from a map for a column value as a key in spark dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I was to get a value from a map from column value as key and create a new column

I have tried the following

```
val testMap = Map("abc" -> "1234", "xyz" -> "3456")

def checkthemap (testmap: Map[String, String], key: String) : String = {
    val value = testmap.get(key)
    if (value == null) "" else value.toString
}

val testDF = analysis
    .withColumn("test", lit(checkthemap(testMap,$"col")))
```

Method accepts the string not the column. How do I change my withColumn statement to send column value as string to a method.

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer is *very inefficient* and unnecessarily complicated. Instead you should just treat `testMap` as a literal. Import the following

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{coalesce, lit, typedLit}
```

convert map to column:

```
val testMapCol = typedLit(testMap)
```

and just select:

```
df.withColumn("value", coalesce(testMapCol($"col"), lit(""))
```

Comment: For some reason, I dont want to create a map to a column or a dataframe. I want to access it from the method itself. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: @user11425401 any advice on this UDF issue plz   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63935600/writing-udf-for-looks-up-in-the-map-in-java-giving-unsupported-literal-type-clas

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a UDF (user defined function) that takes the column as the `key` for the passed-in lookup Map to return the corresponding Map value, as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

def getMapValue(m: Map[String, String], defaultValue: String) = udf{
  (key: String) => m.getOrElse(key, defaultValue)
}

val df = Seq(
  (1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")
).toDF("id", "key")

val lookupMap = Map("a" -> "xx", "c" -> "zz")

df.withColumn("value", getMapValue(lookupMap, "")($"key")).show
// +---+---+-----+
// | id|key|value|
// +---+---+-----+
// |  1|  a|   xx|
// |  2|  b|     |
// |  3|  c|   zz|
// +---+---+-----+
```

EDIT: See the other answer for a solution using built-in Spark functions which generally perform better than UDFs.

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues with the previous answer, since I can not add in a column with element_at. Try (spark 3+)

```
df.withColumn(soureColName, map_values(map_filter(typedLit(testMap),(k, _) => k === col("id")))(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or even simpler from spark 2.4.x

```
List(Map("a" -> "b")).toDF("map").select("map.a").show()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use the built-in function element_at.

Its definition is: Returns element of array at given index in value if column is array. **Returns value for the given key in value if column is map.**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{element_at, col, typedLit}
df.withColumn("value", element_at(typedLit(testMap), col("colName")))
```

Comment: element_at receives a literal with the data type of the key as the second parameter, so using column object instead throws an exception.

Comment: @Vichoko, since 2.4.0 it receives (Column, Any)